# remove extra "WWW_" using sql SUBSTRING

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

In the Name_code column, we have these types of

```
WWW_XX_YYYY
XX_YYYY
XX_E100
XX_MESE
WWW_XX_MESE
WWW_XX_TECH
```

I want O/P the value like this

```
XX_YYYY
YYYY
E100
MESE
XX_MESE
XX_TECH
```

`SUBSTR(Name_code,4, length(Name_Code)-3)` i tried this but no result

How will do That?

Comment: I don't understand the problem statement. Can you share some sample data, the result you're trying to get and the actual result you're getting?

Comment: How should your `substring` knows you want to remove this parts in the first one string only? :-)

Comment: @Mureinik Could you please check  the above Question now .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `instr` to find the index of the first underscore (`_`), and then `substr` from the character after that to the end of the table:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(mycol, INSTR(mycol, '_') + 1)
FROM   mytable
```